# Difficulty using mySQL_num_rows in PHP

Tags: php, mysql

```
$i_id = $_GET['iiSL'];   

require_once('../include/dbc.php');    

$sql = "SELECT invite_id FROM invite_requests WHERE invite_id = '$i_id'";
$result = mysql_query($sql);
if(mysql_num_rows($result == 1))
{
echo 'GOOD ID EXISTS';
//ECHO IS JUST TO TEST  
} 
else
{
echo 'BAD ID IS NOT IN DB';
//ECHO IS JUST TO TEST
}
```

Why is this not working? It's driving me insane.

ERROR 
`Warning: mysql_num_rows(): supplied argument is not a valid MySQL result resource`

All spelling, grammar, syntax, and case is correct. URL is passing the `$i_id` variable. It echo's out correctly.

What am I doing wrong?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There is a typo in the condition..try this..

```
if(mysql_num_rows($result) == 1)
```

You are passing result of `$result == 1` to `mysql_num_rows` which expects a result resouce of `mysql_query()`..:)

Answer (score 0):

change the code as

```
$query1=mysql_query("SELECT count(invite_id) as total FROM invite_requests WHERE invite_id = '$i_id';");
$row = mysql_fetch_array($query1);
if ($row["total"]>"0")
{
echo 'GOOD ID EXISTS';
//ECHO IS JUST TO TEST  
} 
else
{
echo 'BAD ID IS NOT IN DB';
//ECHO IS JUST TO TEST
}           {
```

try this